# Symfony form validation pass array values

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, validation

I'm new to Symfony. Here I'm trying to validate JSON parameters but I can't read array values. `customer` is my json object without array it's working. If I add array for bulk data insert I can't read array values.

My code:

```
$mydata = $request->get('customer');
$formOptions = [];
$formOptions['isactive'] = true;
foreach($mydata as $val)
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
        'customer',
        CustomerRegistrationFormType::class,
        null,
        $formOptions
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
        return "sucess";
    }
    else{
        return $this->view($form->getErrors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Here my JSON request parameters:

```
{

    "customer" :
    [

        {
            "firstName": "asdfasdfasdfsdf",
            "lastName": "asfd",
            "gender": "male",
            "email": "sddssddsdkj@sdf.vb",
            "phone": "1232547890",
            "birthDate": "1991-08-22",
            "createdAt": "2017-09-08T11:18:35.605630+00:00",

            "Number": "2331313423",
            "agreement1": "true",
            "agreement2": "true",
            "agreement3": "true",
            "referral_email": "sdjndsdfreksjd@cgh.fg"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "ldkfasdfsdmnlsmn",
            "lastName": "sjdasdffn",
            "gender": "male",
            "email": "sddssdasdfsdfff23dsdkj@sdf.vb",
            "phone": "1232111890",
            "birthDate": "1991-08-22",
            "createdAt": "2017-09-08T11:18:35.605630+00:00",

            "Number": "8824413423",
            "agreement1": "true",
            "agreement2": "true",
            "agreement3": "true",
            "referral_email": "sdsdf12jndrsdeksjd@cgh.fg"
        }
    ]    
 }
```

How to send array values into `get('form.factory')`?

Inside the `foreach`, all objects have array elements. How do I send these array elements into

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
            'customer',
            CustomerRegistrationFormType::class,
            null,
            $formOptions
        )
```

I can use $val instead of customer(object name) but it's not working. If I remove array and sent single object, it's working.

my CustomerRegistrationFormType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'First name',
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
        ]);
        $builder->add('lastName', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Last name',
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
        ]);
        $builder->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Gender',
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => [
                'male' => 'male',
                'female' => 'female',
            ],
        ]);
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, [
            'label' => 'Email',
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new Email(),
            ],
        ]);
        $builder->add('phone', EmailType::class, [
            'label' => 'Phone',
            'required' => false,
        ]);
        $builder->add('birthDate', DateType::class, [
            'label' => 'Birth date',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        ]);
        $builder->add('createdAt', DateTimeType::class, [
            'label' => 'Creation date',
            'required' => false,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => DateTimeType::HTML5_FORMAT,
        ]);
$builder->add('Number', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Loyalty card number',
            'required' => false,
        ]);

        $builder->add('agreement1', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
            ],
        ]);
        $builder->add('agreement2', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => false,
        ]);
        $builder->add('agreement3', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => false,
        ]);
        $builder->add('referralemail', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Kabilan, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you show the CustomerRegistrationFormType class?

Comment: @halfer I guess the problem was that while I was editing, the author of the post made a couple of changes. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Ah yes @Roberto, apologies - I can see now the editing times are close together. Thanks.